# How to fix tribonacci series function when using generators

Tags: python-3.x

Following is my approach to return the `n` element in Tribonacci series

```
def tri(n,seq = [1, 1, 1]):
   for i in range(n-2):
      seq = seq[1:] + [sum(seq)]
   return seq[-1]
```

I get the correct result when passing argument through `print()`.

```
print(tri(10))
```

Output : 193

However, when using `generator(using repl.it)`, I get error of `can only concatenate tuple (not"list") to tuple`

I am using below for generator

```
def tri_generator():    
for i in range(1000):        
    yield (i, (1, 1, 1))
    yield (i, (1, 0, 1))
    yield (i, (1, 2, 3))
```

Not sure what I am missing? Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

Here's a simple generator *(you can clean up the code as you may like)*:

```
def tri_generator():
    i = 0
    seq = [1, 1, 1]
    while True:
        seq = [seq[1], seq[2], seq[0] + seq[1] + seq[2]]
        yield i, seq
        i += 1  

    n = 10
    xx = tri_generator()
    for i in range(n - 2):
        print(next(xx))  

## Output:
## (0, [1, 1, 3])
## (1, [1, 3, 5])
## (2, [3, 5, 9])
## (3, [5, 9, 17])
## (4, [9, 17, 31])
## (5, [17, 31, 57])
## (6, [31, 57, 105])
## (7, [57, 105, 193])
```